# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set (can't find Wi-Fi on Lubuntu 19.10)

Tags: networking, wifi, drivers, network-interface, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 19.10. 
The problem is I can't find the Wi-Fi network (Wi-Fi is enabled in nm-tray). 
Then I tried to check my drivers, but when I go to "Preferences" → "Additional Drivers" I get this message:

```
          LXQt sudo
Child 'sudo' process failed!    
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

[image: screenshot containing above error window]

I cannot even see available Wi-Fi networks. 
I tried to see `iwconfig` in Terminal but I see the same error.

I have USB tethering via mobile phone but I'm not able to have my phone connected to the computer all the time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what you did before: the error message indicates that you seem to have changed permissions of (at least) `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: I didn't edit anything before this, it's fresh Lubuntu installation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that Lubuntu 19.10 is EOL, meaning no longer supported. You should upgrade to 20.04, the current LTS, or downgrade to 18.04 which is also a LTS release.

But, the problem here is that someone has changed the permissions for `/usr/bin`.

To fix this, you need to take ownership (and change the permissions) of the directory and files.

Open your terminal and enter the following:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

And that should solve your problem. This assumes this is the only symptom. If you've changed the permissions for multiple directories, there will be more work involved.

Comment: The lubuntu.net domain is not the real Lubuntu site. That's [lubuntu.me](https://lubuntu.me/). To go to the official pages, when you don't already know, you should use [this link](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and follow the links from there. Either way, the solution above should get you squared away with your `sudo` issue and you can work your way from there to get your wifi issues resolved.

Comment: I tried your commands, but no responses given in Terminal.
When I add 'sudo' before your commands, it gives me the same error: usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

I downloaded Lubuntu 19.10 from lubuntu.net, there it says the latest version is 19.04
I've just realised that there is lubuntu.me website, sorry! I'm just downloading from lubuntu.me (version 20.04) ...

Comment: Yeah, let's go that route. It'll be much easier - and probably faster. Grab the latest 20.04 (like you're doing now) ISO and re-install. When you're doing the installation, you can pick 'something else' (during the partition stage) and it will let you just install it over the existing install while preserving /home. Otherwise, backup /home (if you have anything you want to keep) and just copy it back to the new install.

Comment: Thank you! While installing do I need to select mounting point to: / or /home or /bin ?

Comment: Just the `/` should do it. Backup `/home` if there's anything in there you want to keep. If there's nothing you want to keep then just go ahead and wipe the disk and do a full install.

Comment: Check what file-system you used for the install. If you used FAT or NTFS,  then you would get this problem (I am surprised that it dose not stop you installing, with a big warning). You should use ext4 (there are some others that will work, but let us not worry about that).

Comment: @control-alt-delor - Good catch. I was unaware that it'd even attempt to install on either of those file systems.